# Why can I run my ASP.NET Core MVC app from command line, but NOT from Visual Studio by hitting F5?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have built a sample ASP.NET Core MVC app, the project was setup from the command line. I was able to run the app using `dotnet watch run` command, but I could not start the app from Visual Studio by hitting the <kbd>F5</kbd> key.

Why is this?

I have installed a **CA certificate** from commands (one to remove existing and other to add new)

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

Could this be causing the problem, if so how do I fix it? (I need to keep the new certificate as well)

In the solutions folder, there are folders for the `ClientApp` (Angular) and the server app (ASP.NET Core MVC).

When I hit <kbd>F5</kbd>, I get an error (the same error for both ports 5000 and 5001):

[image]

Comment: What is the Visual Studio debug target? Is it IIS Express or the Application?

Comment: @Anuraj thats solved my issue, it had IIS as target, thanks heaps!